# Specific String Produces StringOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, indexoutofrangeexception

My Program seems to Produce an String Index out of Range Error only for this Particular Input. The same code is working for other inputs. Will add the Output Screenshot and Code Below. I searched around - The fact that this error turns up only for a Single Input makes it tough to solve.

```
               int ind,len,vallen,amount,credits = 0;
               String credit; 
               String value,item;
               float oneamount;
              // System.out.println("Credit Assignment");
               ind=input.indexOf("is");
               credit = input.substring(0, ind-1);
           //       System.out.println(credit);
                 //Seperate the Quantity and Item Name from the String
                  len = credit.length();
                  vallen= credit.lastIndexOf(" ");
                  value= credit.substring(0,vallen);          //**Line 59**
                  item = credit.substring(vallen,len).trim();
                  System.out.println(value);
```

[image]

Comment: what is in line 59? also post the working code. for us to debug

Comment: `credit = input.substring(0, ind-1);` What if `ind` is 0?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - or -1 ? :P

Comment: Post the stack trace, not a screenshot.

Comment: I search for Index of "is" . Alright. I guess the search returns the index of 1 because "pish" contains "is". Right ?

Comment: If there is no "IS" in your String you will get this exception, because you try to `substring(0, -2);` and that is not possible. Add an If statement, to make sure you have an index >0. If you need more help give us an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And please format your code. It's all over the place at the moment. Do you really need all of that code to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Jon Skeet, 700K that's more than all points that I have in all sites on the web.

Comment: "The fact that this error turns up only for a Single Input makes it tough to solve" - no, it makes it *really easy* to solve. You write a short but complete program with that input hard-coded, and you remove bits of it until you've got *just* the problematic part. That's likely to solve the issue for you, and if it doesn't it means you'd have a really good question to post - rather than one without the relevant input, a picture instead of a stack trace, and a large incomplete section of code instead of a short but complete program...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crash with `pish pish Gold is 40 Credits`

> I guess the search returns the index of 1 because "pish" contains
>   "is". Right ?

Right. `ind` is 1, `credit` is an empty string, and since no space can be found, `vallen` is -1 and the exception occurs on the next line.

Answer (score 1):

[String.lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String)) returns `-1` if the specific search string is not found.

so in the following line

```
vallen= credit.lastIndexOf(" ");
```

if credit doesn't contains " " then vallen will be -1.

so

```
value= credit.substring(0,vallen); will throw error.
```

Comment: It could return 0 as well in `input.substring(0, ind-1);`, which will also cause an exception because OP is doing `ind - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was with

> ind=input.indexOf("is");

This returned 1 as Pish contained the String "is".  So now I used

> ind=input.lastIndexOf("is");

And the code is working fine. Thanks for the responses. Am a beginner. Will Format my code better and Include Stack Trace instead of Screenshots in the future.